# scrapy script works fine in shell but doesnt on crawler

Tags: python, shell, scrapy, web-crawler

hi i have a script that when typed in the shell (up to the for loop) works just fine, it shows each a tag nicely.
but when i put it in scrapy it goes completly crazy and shows nothing.
the script is supposed to write whats yielded in a json file but the file just statys empty or is filled with empty commas

import scrapy

```
class SgbdSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "sgbd"

    start_urls = [
        "http://www.sante.gouv.sn/actualites/"
    ]

    def parse(self,response):
        base = "http://www.sante.gouv.sn/actualites"
        for link in response.css(".card-title a"):
            title = link.css("a::text").get()
            href = link.css("a::attr(href)").extract()
            yield
            {
                "title" : title,
                "href" : href
            }
            # next step for each href, parse again and get link in that page for pdf file
            #   pdf link can easily be collected with response.css(".file a::attr(href)").get()
            #   then write that link in a json file
        next_page = response.css("li.pager-next a::attr(href)").get()
        if next_page is not None:
            next_page = response.urljoin(next_page)
            yield scrapy.Request(next_page,callback=self.parse)
```

thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try `for link in response.css(".card-title"):`